# Getting wrong results in Search Cursor of ArcPy/Python script?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.1, cursor

I have two functions:

1. First one will crated the feature layer
2. second one will access the same created layer and prints the result.

**when i run my script first time it will print the wrong results. when i run it second time it will prints correct result...**

**Wrong Result Script running 1st Time:**

getting access to map layer 2

(repeated many times)

**.**

**Correct Result: Running script second time**
1. layer which is creating contains only 5 Rows so my script prints only 5 messages

getting access to map layer 1

repeated for all layers.

**Script:**

```
# import system modules   
import arcpy  
import math  
import sys    
import traceback    
from arcpy import env  

# Class to Build Boundry of Districts  


class Build_Boundry:  

   def __init__(self, workSpace,mapLayerFinal,censusLayer,totalDistricts,mxdLocation):  
      self.workSpace = workSpace  
      self.censusLayer = censusLayer  
      self.mapLayerFinal = mapLayerFinal  
      self.totalDistricts = totalDistricts  
      self.mxdLocation = mxdLocation  

   # Function to Calculate Average of Total Voters in each District  
   def boundry(self):  
      arcpy.AddMessage("Building Boundry of Districts ")  
      if arcpy.Exists(self.mapLayerFinal):  
          arcpy.AddMessage("Layer Already Exist.....")  
          print(self.mapLayerFinal)  
      else:  
          arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(self.censusLayer, self.mapLayerFinal,"DISTRICT_ID BETWEEN 1 AND "+str(self.totalDistricts),self.workSpace)  

          # Execute Dissolve using LANDUSE and TAXCODE as Dissolve Fields  
          arcpy.Dissolve_management(self.mapLayerFinal, str(self.workSpace)+"/"+str(self.mapLayerFinal), "DISTRICT_ID", "","MULTI_PART", "DISSOLVE_LINES")  
          print(self.mapLayerFinal)  
          arcpy.AddMessage("Boundry of Districts Calculated")  

          mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(self.mxdLocation)  
          df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd, "")[0]  
          addLayer = arcpy.mapping.Layer(self.mapLayerFinal)  
          arcpy.mapping.AddLayer(df, addLayer,"BOTTOM")  
          mxd.save()  
          arcpy.RefreshTOC()  

          del mxd, addLayer  

      return;  

# Class to Calculate Compactness  
class Calculate_Compactness:  
   def __init__(self, workSpace,mapLayerFinal):  
   self.workSpace = workSpace  
   self.mapLayerFinal = mapLayerFinal  

   # Function to Calculate Compactness  
   def compactness_quotient(self):  
      arcpy.AddMessage("Calculating Compactness Quotient")  
      with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(self.mapLayerFinal,["Shape_Area","DISTRICT_ID","Shape_Length"]) as rows:  
          print "layer "+str(self.mapLayerFinal)  
          for row in rows:  
              area = row[0]  
              district_id = row[1]   
              perimeter = row[2]  

              print "getting access to map layer "+str(district_id)  

          print "Calculating Compactness Quotient Process Complete"  

      return;  


folder = "C:/Users/Abrar ahmad/Desktop/CASES/Rural/Case_1_Boundary_Input"  
mxdLocation = r"C:/Users/Abrar ahmad/Desktop/CASES/Rural/Case_1_Boundary_Input/New_Rwp_Cencus.mxd"  
workSpace = "C:/Users/Abrar ahmad/Desktop/CASES/Rural/Case_1_Boundary_Input/Selected_BU2.gdb" 
env.workspace = workSpace  


censusLayer = "Rural_Area_Rwp"   
districtsLayer = "Existing_District_Boundary"   
totalDistricts = int(5)  


mapLayerFinal = str(districtsLayer)+"_map"    

# Function to Build Boundry  
boundry = Build_Boundry(workSpace,mapLayerFinal,censusLayer,totalDistricts,mxdLocation)  
boundry.boundry()  


cc = Calculate_Compactness(workSpace,mapLayerFinal)  
cc.compactness_quotient()
```

Comment: Alinna, GIS.SE is not a debugging service, I had an attempt at working out what you're trying to do but can only get a vague idea.. most wont even bother reading such a long code block. All I can advise is check your temporary results and see if there's a problem there (perhaps the dissolve isn't working properly) perhaps the problem is arising from bad data.

Comment: @MichaelMiles-Stimson ok thanks , found the problem... will consider your suggestions in future

Comment: Just saying that not many will read through a large code block, try to keep it down to just what's causing the problem; you can always add more if requested. One method to try to filter it look at your temp layers/feature classes and find the one that's not what you're expecting and limit the code to what produced the last good value and the first bad value...

Answer (score 1):

There is a variable which colliding in MakeFeatureLayer and Dissolve_Management. changed it into **temp_layer**

```
arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(self.censusLayer, "tmp_Layer","DISTRICT_ID BETWEEN 1 AND "+str(self.totalDistricts),self.workSpace)   

# Execute Dissolve using LANDUSE and TAXCODE as Dissolve Fields   
arcpy.Dissolve_management("tmp_Layer", str(self.workSpace)+"/"+str(self.mapLayerFinal), "DISTRICT_ID", "","MULTI_PART", "DISSOLVE_LINES")
```